# How to avoid initializing HibernateProxy when invoking toString() on it?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have following mappings:

Author:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Author {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Access(PROPERTY)
  private Long id;
}
```

Book:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Access(PROPERTY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  private Author author;
}
```

Following code demonstrates the issue:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        saveBookAndAuthor();


        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Book book = em.find(Book.class, 1L);
        Author author = book.getAuthor();
        System.out.println(author.getClass());
        author.toString();
    }

    private void saveBookAndAuthor() {
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Author author = new Author();
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setAuthor(author);
        entityManager.persist(author);
        entityManager.persist(book);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Here is a part of logs:

```
class com.example.demo.Author_$$_jvst5e0_0
2017-11-22 22:12:56.671 DEBUG 9426 --- [           main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl       : Initializing proxy: [com.example.demo.Author#1]
2017-11-22 22:12:56.671 DEBUG 9426 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select author0_.id as id1_0_0_ from author author0_ where author0_.id=?
```

`author.toString();` line causes the Author entity initialization even if  the `toString()` method was not overridden.
Is there a way to avoid it?

Spring boot version: 1.5.8.RELEASE

Hibernate version: 5.0.12.Final

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making `toString()` `final` solved the issue.

**Background:**

I've spent some time to figure out what is really going on.
Here is what I've found

`Hibernate` uses `Javassist` for runtime proxy generation.

Generated proxies do implement [`javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject`](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject.html) interface which has `setHandler(MethodHandler)` method used by Hibernate to set [`org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer`](https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/proxy/pojo/javassist/JavassistLazyInitializer.java#L101) ( which in turn intercepts method calls (including `toString()`).

When `toString()` is invoked the original method should proceed ([`JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(Object, Method, Method,Object[]`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/proxy/pojo/javassist/JavassistLazyInitializer.java#L73)):

```
if ( result == INVOKE_IMPLEMENTATION ) {
  Object target = getImplementation();
...
```

But before it Hibernate initializes the proxy ([`AbstractLazyInitializer`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/proxy/AbstractLazyInitializer.java#L258)):

```
@Override
public final Object getImplementation() {
    initialize();
    return target;
}
```

`final` methods are not intercepted, so adding `final` modifier to `toString()` will solve the issue.

But remember that if  your `toString()` access fields directly and the proxy is not initialized you will see `null`s even if these fields are really present.
You can use getters in to avoid this. *But do you really need to trigger initialization to print your entity to log?*

Please let me know if I'm wrong or there is a better solution

Comment: Addition of the final `modifier` to `toString()` didn't solve the issue in my case. Are you sure this should do the trick?

Comment: @StijnV just tried to add `final` modifier to my local example, it helped. Maybe you can share simple reproducible example?

Comment: It turned out to be logging - hidden in aspects - that was always forcing the initialization of the proxy. So, I cannot blame the final modifier anymore.