# Kotlin inheritance and JPA

Tags: jpa, inheritance, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement inheritance with Kotlin and JPA. My abstract base class (annotated with `@Entity`) holds the ID (annotated with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue`) and other metadata, like createDate, etc. I'm getting several errors from Hibernate, one for each field except the ID:

> org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer - HHH000112: Getters of lazy classes cannot be final: com.example.BaseEntity.createDate

As I've read I need to include the open keyword for each property.

I have 3 questions regarding this:

1. Why do I have to do that in the superclass, and don't need in subclass? I'm not overriding those properties.
2. Why isn't it complaining about the ID?
3. It seems to work without the open keyword, then why is the error logged?

Edit:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class BaseEntity(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long = 0,
    val createdAt: Instant = Instant.now()
)

@Entity
class SubClass(
    val someProperty: String = ""
) : BaseEntity()
```

I'm using the JPA plugin for Gradle, which I believe creates the noarg constructor, that's why I don't have to specify everything nullable.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post code of your entities please?

Comment: if you use gradle do you have kotlin-jpa plugin and kotlin-allopen & kotlin-noarg dependencies?

Comment: @caco3 added some code :)

Comment: @IEE1394 I've added noarg and allopen, same result.

Comment: is the id generated if you use 0? i think you have to use null value to generate id. what about @Column annotations?

Comment: @IEE1394 yes it's correctly generated, I guess by reflection. If I use nullable I have to assert everywhere, it's inconvenient. The `@Column` is assumed by `@Entity`.

Comment: It is correctly generated even if you use primitive (non nullable `Long` property). See the first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994261/default-constructor-getting-executed-many-times-when-tried-to-load-records-in-hi/53995102#53995102) answer (disclaimer: it is my answer)

Comment: @Peter thx for the hint .. yes you have to assert everywhere and its not nice :-) because 0 is a valid ID i thaught it is maybe a problem :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logged error has to do with [**lazy loading**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-get-reference).

Hibernate `extends` entities at runtime to enable it. It is done by intercepting an access to properties when an entity is loaded lazily.

Kotlin has flipped the rules and all classes are `final` by default there. It is the reason why we're advised to add an `open` keyword.

If a property is not `open` hibernate cannot intercept access to it because `final` methods cannot be overridden. Hence the error.

> Why isn't it complaining about the ID?

Because `@Id` is always loaded. There is no need to intercept access to it.

> It seems to work without the `open` keyword, then why is the error logged?

The key word here is *seems*. It may introduce subtle bugs.

Consider the following `@Entity`:

```java
@Entity
public class Book {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String title;

  public final Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public final String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

And the `@Test`:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
  EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  // signal here
  Book book = new Book();
  book.setId(1L);
  book.setTitle("myTitle");  
  entityManager.persist(book);
  // noise
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
  entityManager.close();

  entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  // signal
  Book reference = entityManager.getReference(Book.class, 1L);
  String title = reference.getTitle();
  assertNull(title); // passes

  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
  entityManager.close();
}
```

This test **passes** but it should not (and fails if `getTitle` is not `final`). 
This would be hard to notice

> Why do I have to do that in the superclass, and don't need in subclass? I'm not overriding those properties.

Looks like Hibernate **gives up** when it sees `final` `@Entity`.

Add `open` to `SubClass` and you will the precious:

```
2019-05-02 23:27:27.500 ERROR 5609 --- [           main] o.h.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer      : HHH000112: Getters of lazy classes cannot be final: com.caco3.hibernateanswer.SubClass.someProperty
```

**See also**:

- [final methods on entity silently breaks lazy proxy loading](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12121)
- [How to avoid initializing HibernateProxy when invoking toString() on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442454/how-to-avoid-initializing-hibernateproxy-when-invoking-tostring-on-it) - my *old* question (note that Hibernate uses [Byte Buddy](https://bytebuddy.net/#/) these days).

**PS**

Did you forget to include `@MappedSuperclass` on `BaseEntity`?

Without the annotation it should fail with something like:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.caco3.hibernateanswer.SubClass
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the deep insight! For the PS part: the three code ticks omitted the `@Entity` annotation, I moved it to another line to be visible. :)